# Rails 3.1 delete redirect, suggestions don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have what seems to be a common problem where I generated a standard scaffold in Rails 3.1. When I try to click on "Destroy", it does the same thing as if I clicked "Show". 
As some people have suggested I made sure I have:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> 
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

in my head tag, however, when I look at the page source, this is what gets created:

defaults.js doesn't exsist of course.

Can anybody help?
Thank you

Adding an edit, the full tag actually looks like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery.dataTables.js", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false","application", :defaults %> 
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

So I do have "application", and in my app/assets/javascripts/application.js  I do have jquery and jquery_ujs

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Rails 3.1, try this instead:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Also, make sure your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file has references to both `jquery` and `jquery_ujs`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve this by including rails.js from "https://raw.github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/master/src/rails.js"

Apparently